# Erro ao executar SaveChanges EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Antes estava funcionando normalmente.

Agora eu enfrento esse problema na hora de executar esse código:

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //erro aqui 
}
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Exception: Spatial types and functions are not available for this
>   provider because the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' version 10
>   or higher could not be found.

Alguma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instale o "Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012" abaixo:

- X86 - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239643&clcid=0x409
- X64 - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239644&clcid=0x409

Comment: Danilo, sua resposta me ajudou muito, porem meu site está hospedado em uma empresa e não pode mexer no server dele. Então eu fiz um pequeno tutorial, na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa para quem não pode mexer no servidor.

Instale um pacote do [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/):

`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types -Version 14.0.1016.290`

Depois vai no arquivo ***Global.asax.cs***:

```
using SqlServerTypes;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Enables use of spatial data types
    SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
    SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName =
    "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
}
```

E seja feliz